# Is it appropriate to send the abstract to the editor and ask him if my paper is a good fit with the journal?

Tags: paper-submission

There is a very good journal in my area, but I have never submitted any paper there. Now I have a new study, which I think might be a fit with the journal but I'm not sure. So I want to send the abstract to the editor and ask him whether it's a good fit. If he thinks it's not, I wouldn't waste my time submitting it there. But is it appropriate to ask the editor to do this? What would an editor usually do if he/she receives such a request?

Comment: Welcome to AC.SE. Please take a look at our [help]. We have two sites, I move the question to the correct *side*

Comment: Does the journal have any instructions regarding *pre-submission inquiries*?

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  The benefit is really not to get wrapped up with a long review cycle for something that doesn't make it in anyways when you could have gone elsewhere.

That said, I think the very top journals (in science at least) like Science, Nature, PRL are pretty up front about weeding out stuff that is not notable and also committed to some speed in publishing.  So you might just get a fast answer on notability, regardless by running through the regular submissions process.  "We just don't publish cuprates that don't superconduct" was an actual editor communication from one of those magazines.

Comment: I am not sure if you have multiple "guest" accounts, if you do, please follow https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge them. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add to the answer: Email the editor directly, rather than going via the journal (which will add a delay).